# sendmail not working Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, ubuntu-16.04

Ive installed sendmail on my server using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
sudo sendmailconfig
```

Before running `sudo sendmailconfig` ive added my servers hostname to my `/etc/hosts`.
Now when I try to run sendmail it just stucks.

```
> echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v my@mail.de
mp@borntocreate.de... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 localhost.localdomain ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3; Sun, 12 Nov 2017 13:02:49 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
250-localhost.localdomain Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<ubuntu@localhost.localdomain> SIZE=23 AUTH=ubuntu@localhost.localdomain
250 2.1.0 <ubuntu@localhost.localdomain>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<my@mail.de>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <my@mail.de>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
```

I cant figure out how to fix this.
I have an firewall enabled but all my outbounding ports are allowed.

The email is added to mail queue but timed out.

```
> sudo mailq

vACD6HYe002871*       0 Sun Nov 12 13:06 <ubuntu@localhost.localdomain>
                 (Deferred: Connection timed out with aspmx2.googlemail.com.)
                 <my@mail.de>
```

Comment: 1. Use better test message `(echo "Subject: sendmail test"; echo ; echo "test body")  | sendmail -i -v my@mail.de` 2. As root push the message i queue in verbose mode `sendmail -v -qIvACD6HYe002871` 3. What is reported by `hostname --fqdn`